# Flex: Unable to set headerRenderer programmatically

Tags: apache-flex, dynamic, datagrid, renderer, flex-spark

I need to set the headerRenderer for my spark datagrid programmatically because I need to assign some properties to it (start and end time). This data is fetched from a database and needs to be assigned to this headerrenderer after being loaded.

While it is no problem to programmatically set my itemRenderer, I find no way of doing the same for the headerRenderer.

Here is a simplified piece of code:

Main

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
               xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
               xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" minWidth="955" minHeight="600">
    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[           
            protected function button1_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
            {
                customHeaderColumn.headerRenderer = new ClassFactory(myHeaderRenderer); 
                customHeaderColumn.itemRenderer = new ClassFactory(myItemRenderer);
            }

        ]]>
    </fx:Script>
    <s:layout>
        <s:VerticalLayout />
    </s:layout>
    <s:DataGrid width="100%">
        <s:dataProvider>
            <s:ArrayList>
                <fx:Object name="record"/>
            </s:ArrayList>
        </s:dataProvider>
        <s:columns>
            <s:ArrayList>
                <s:GridColumn id="customHeaderColumn" headerText="Column 1"/>
            </s:ArrayList>
        </s:columns>
    </s:DataGrid>
    <s:Button label="change" click="button1_clickHandler(event)"/>
</s:Application>
```

myItemRenderer

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:GridItemRenderer xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
                    xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
                    xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" clipAndEnableScrolling="true">
    <s:Label top="9" left="7" text="item"/>
</s:GridItemRenderer>
```

myHeaderRenderer

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:GridItemRenderer xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
                    xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
                    xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" clipAndEnableScrolling="true">
    <s:Label top="9" left="7" text="header"/>
</s:GridItemRenderer>
```

When clicking the button, you can see the itemRenderer changing, the headerRenderer, however, stays the same.

Comment: Smells like a bug. If you just want to set some properties, you could create the header renderer inline (just like you do with the `dataProvider` and `columns` properties) and bind the properties.

Comment: @RIAstar That seems to work ! Doesn't solve the question, but solves my problem, thank you !

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you can force it by executing:

```
myDataGrid.columnHeaderGroup.layout.clearVirtualLayoutCache();
```

I've copied this line from DataGrid.as set columns method:

```
public function set columns(value:IList):void
{
    if (setGridProperty("columns", value))
    {
        if (columnHeaderGroup)
        {
            columnHeaderGroup.layout.clearVirtualLayoutCache();
            columnHeaderGroup.invalidateSize();
            columnHeaderGroup.invalidateDisplayList();
        }

        dispatchChangeEvent("columnsChanged");
    }
}
```